# Using carouFredSel and jQuery masonry in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-masonry, caroufredsel

I am trying to use [**carouFredSel**](http://docs.dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/) with [**Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in a Twitter Bootstrap 3 layout. The masonry working fine as expected. However, when I use caroufredsel, the masonry layout losses and comes in a single column as `col-xs-12` of bootstrap.

**HTML Markup**:

```
<div class="container" id="main-content">
    <div class="row masonry">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x525" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4  masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x200" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <p>Phasellus felis mi, imperdiet eu vestibulum commodo, viverra at leo. Proin interdum vehicula sapien vitae ultricies. Donec at leo blandit, malesuada nisi vitae, molestie odio. Phasellus pellentesque neque eu felis aliquet laoreet. Etiam ultricies, ligula nec tristique vulputate, nisi ipsum imperdiet lorem, vel molestie ligula justo vitae nulla. Vivamus a scelerisque enim. Nulla lacinia sed elit at laoreet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x200" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-4 col-sm-2 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <div class="flex-video widescreen">
                <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/3pAnRKD4raY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x150" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x150" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a leo enim. Nulla molestie nec justo non imperdiet. Aliquam tempus placerat lorem quis gravida. Nam ultrices elit at ultricies sodales. Proin vulputate hendrerit gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row masonry">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x525" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4  masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x200" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <p>Phasellus felis mi, imperdiet eu vestibulum commodo, viverra at leo. Proin interdum vehicula sapien vitae ultricies. Donec at leo blandit, malesuada nisi vitae, molestie odio. Phasellus pellentesque neque eu felis aliquet laoreet. Etiam ultricies, ligula nec tristique vulputate, nisi ipsum imperdiet lorem, vel molestie ligula justo vitae nulla. Vivamus a scelerisque enim. Nulla lacinia sed elit at laoreet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x200" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-4 col-sm-2 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <div class="flex-video widescreen">
                <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/3pAnRKD4raY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x150" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x150" class="img-responsive" alt="img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-3 col-sm-4 masonry-item mrg-20">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean a leo enim. Nulla molestie nec justo non imperdiet. Aliquam tempus placerat lorem quis gravida. Nam ultrices elit at ultricies sodales. Proin vulputate hendrerit gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is My Javascript code:**

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        var $container = $('.masonry');
        // initialize
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: '.masonry-item',
            itemSelector: '.masonry-item'
        });
        $container.masonry('on', 'layoutComplete', function () {
       //     $container.css('float', 'left');
            $("#main-content").carouFredSel({
                width: "100%",
                height: "auto",
                items: {
                    visible: 1,
                    minimum: 1,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%"
                },
                scroll: {
                    items: 1,
                    fx: "fade",
                    easing: "linear",
                    pauseOnHover: true
                },
                auto: {
                    progress: "#progress"
                },
                prev: "left",
                next: "right"
            });
        });
    });
```

I tried with [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/4ke5h/1/) code (*code is above*) and [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/4ke5h/3/) code (*the carousfredsel called separately*), but the layout messed. What I am trying to achieve is:

1. The cols in each row should be responsive and masonry enabled.
2. The slider also should work fine and it also fit to the container properly.
3. If anyone has a solution with isotope or any such other plugins or instead of using carousfredsel any other plugins also can consider.

Ideas/suggestions/solutions are most welcome.